# Import images from another file in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, create-react-app

I am using `create-react-app` to build a simple web page:

*index.js:*

```
import lostImage from './assets/img/illustrations/lost.svg';

function Image(props) {
    return (
        <img src={lostImage} />
    );
}
```

It works as expected, however I plan to import dozens of images, so I decided to move the `import` calls in a separate file in the same directory:

*images.js:*

```
import lostImage from './assets/img/illustrations/lost.svg';
```

*index.js:*

```
import './images.js';

function Image(props) {
    return (
        <img src={lostImage} />
    );
}
```

However I get the `lostImage not defined` error. How do I properly do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export them from images.js file. Then import them to the index.js file to use.

images.js:

```
import lostImage from './assets/img/illustrations/lost.svg';
export { lostImage };
```

index.js:

```
import {lostImage} from './images.js';

function Image(props) {
    return (
        <img src={lostImage} />
    );
}
```

Comment: Any way to import them all at once instead of doing it one by one again inside *index.js*?

Comment: use `import * as images from './images.js';` then.. `images.lostImage` @sdvnksv